# Diagnostic tests for Markov model in R package, "ChannelAttribution"

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, marketing

I am using R version 3.30 on windows OS. I have come across a business problem in marketing of channel attribution that's when I found the aforementioned package. But I wonder, is there a way to validate the results we get from the markov model. How can we make sure that the results we are getting are the actual attribution and they'll hold with the new data. The model tells us 3 things:

1. Transition Probabilities
2. Removal Effects
3. Attribution

What metrics one can check to ensure the robustness of the model?

The help file compares the heuristic models with the markov model but what measure to be used in order to comment that markov model should be used and the attribution through its use is the genuine attribution?

Comment: Wecome to CrossValidated. The information you have provided so far is fairly sparse. Because of that, it may be difficult to weigh in on your question. For example, a robust description of your data would help those familiar with these models to suggest methods that may not be appropriate for other datasets. Please take a look at the following post on [how to ask a good question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated/1483#1483) on the site and fill in some of the gaps.